# client validation is not working when angular and mvc is mixed

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, validation

When I mix angular and mvc, validation of mvc model is not working.
this is my model code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage ="Required")]
public string EmailId { get; set; }
```

this is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.em.EmailId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.em.EmailId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", data_ng_model = "EmailIdem" } })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.em.EmailId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" class="btnAdd" value="Save" data-ng-click="AddEmployee()" />
```

When click save, validation not working.

Comment: have you tried in the decoration to set AllowEmptyString=false ? ..so ..somehting like: [Required(AllowEmtpyString=false,ErrorMessage ="Required")]

Comment: I want to use mvc validator not angular.

Comment: it is MVC validation..